# Ordering of vertices satisfying two conditions.

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

Based on above graph, find the orderings satisfying

1) every vertex other than the last is adjacent to some vertex that comes later in the ordering

2)the final vertex has non-maximal degree

by second condition, it seems that vertex 6 should be the last one since it has non-maximal degree.

However, if you proceed on the left side by ordering vertices from

1,2,3,4,5 so that every vertex is adjacent to vertex that comes later in the ordering.

Since 6 has to be the last one, the next vertex that comes after 5 must be either 7,8,9,10, or 11 but those vertices are not adjacent to 5.

Did I misunderstand something?

For second question,

If a graph is connected and non-regular, is it always possible to order
the vertices so that conditions (1) and (2) are satisfied?

I think this is not possible, since square has all vertices of degree 2 and every vertex has maximal degree.

Is that one counter-example?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Yes, you are misinterpreting something. The condition requires that each vertex (except for the last one, of course) appears before a vertex adjacent to it, but **NOT** that it appears *immediately* before that one. So you can extend the segment that you've already constructed as
$$\ldots,7,1,2,3,4,5,6.$$
Adding $7$ there satisfies the given requirements, because $7$ is adjacent to $6$, which does appear later than $7$ in this ordering.

(2) The square is not a valid counterexample here, because the statement talks about **non-regular** graphs. A graph is *regular* if all its vertices have the same degree. Precisely for the reason that you described (that there wouldn't be a vertex with a non-maximal degree) such graphs are specifically excluded from this statement.

Comment: Thanks!. For the second statement, is there any nice way to approach?

Comment: @lando: To be honest, I haven't thought much about it, and I've never seen this question before, so I don't know an answer off the top of my head. My guess (without any guarantee) is that it is true and could be proven by induction.

Comment: thanks. I will try